# Scrolling bug in iScroll 4 using Mac's trackpad on Firefox 23.0.1

Tags: jquery, firefox, iscroll, requestanimationframe

I'm building webapp that has browser's native scroll disabled and instead of that I'm using iScroll. I encountered following problem with newest Firefox.

Using two-finger-scroll on my MacBook Air with Firefox 23.0.1 the iScroll 4 scrolls only under 10px per scrolling gesture, in older firefox the scroll was smooth as it is on Safari and Chrome and the scroll lenght was many tens of pixels long. If I use ordinary mouse with rolling mouse wheel, the scroll is as it should be.

Folks with macbooks and firefox version 23 can test the issue even on iScroll -demo page, http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/ .

New version Relase notes http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/23.0.1/releasenotes/ says this '
Added unprefixed requestAnimationFrame', that is the only thing updated which might have something to do with it.

I tried to find a solution for the problem from iScroll's code that determines the vendor (moz-, webkit- o- etc.) for css-transfomations and so on, based on current browser. I had no luck with that, unfortunately.

I updated my Firefox to version 23.0.1. Before that problem didn't occur at all and everything worked perfectly.

If somebody has a hunch or fact about the problem I would be thankful!

Cheers,
Pyry

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming problem. Stack Overflow isn't for general tech support questions. I believe that superuser.com is more suited to this kind of question.

Comment: Well I think this has something to do with mousewheel-events or css-transform easing because iScroll is fully based on those. Native scroll works as espected

Comment: Yeah, but you're not doing any coding involving mousewheel-events or css-transform easing. If someone said "I'm building a webapp, and iScroll scrolling isn't working right on Firefox 23.0.1 on some machines; how can I fix it?", that would be a question that fits on SO - and from the sounds of it, the answer would be "this appears to be a bug in Firefox and/or iScroll itself, and not something you can fix". SO is for "How do I solve this programming problem", not "My computer is broken, and there must be programming involved somewhere".

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm gonna edit my poorly placed question. I blindly tought that it's self-explanatory that, if I place question to stackoverflow, there is some coding involved. My bad..

Comment: It's definitely a programming issue for me! Even if it's a bug in Firefox, I still need to figure out how to deal with it for my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this error as well, but in my own code:

http://comic-viewer-dev.appspot.com/view/brad/

Looks like a bug in Firefox 23. I've filed it:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=907275

... but I'd love to find a workaround in the meantime!

Comment: I realize this isn't an answer, per se, but hopefully the bug link will help lead us to an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and good contribution! Let's hope they get to it soon at Mozilla. But yeah, I could use a workaround also!

Comment: They've fixed the bug in Firefox and it'll be appearing in Firefox 24 on Sept. 17th. That's good enough for me... I'm not motivated to work around the issue in the meantime.

Comment: Yeah, that suits me too. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: Note that this issue may be coming back. See:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=907275#c26

I've notified the iScroll folks.